# ListView and get_queryset with two models

Tags: django, django-views

I have 2 models in which I need to do a search:

```
class Movies(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "movies"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Actors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    movies = models.ManyToManyField(Movies, related_name="actors")

    class Meta:
        db_table = "actors"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have a search form and need to search in Movies title and Actors name. I know how to make view for search in one model:

```
class SearchView(ListView):
    template_name = "search_results.html"
    model = Actors

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = Actors.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
        return object_list
```

But how to make when I want to search in two models? **The result should then list the occurrences in actor names and occurrences in movie titles separately in the template.** How to update my View easily?

I tried to add a method get_context_data to extend the context, but unfortunately I don't know how to access the second model in get_query-set. I use default db.sqlite3.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with adding a `get_context_data` function, as in a `ListView` the `get_queryset` function is used for model that the list view is based on. This should work for the `get_context_data` function:

```
def get_context_data(self,*args,**kwargs):
   context = super(SearchView,self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
   
   query = self.request.GET.get('q')
   movies = Movies.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)

   context['movies_list'] = movies
   return context
```

Then in your template you would access the movies by the context variable name `{{ movies_list }}`.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with the rest of your project.